# Parameter 0 of method commandLineRunner error whenever I run my main app

Tags: spring-boot

I cant seem to solve the issue here! Some help will be great!

Parameter 0 of method commandLineRunner in com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema.ScreenSavvyApplication required abean of type 'com.project314.screenSavvy.dao.UserDAO' that could not be found.

UserAccount.java

```
package com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name= "user_account")

public class UserAccount {

    // define fields 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id; 
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name; 
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name; 
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email; 
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    
    //define no arg constructor 
    
    public UserAccount() {
    } 
    
    //define constructor

    public UserAccount(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    
    //define toString() 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserAccount [id=" + id + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", email=" + email
                + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

UserDAO.java

```
package com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.project314.screenSavvy.entity.UserAccount;

@Component
@Service
public interface UserDAO {
    void save(UserAccount userAcc);
}
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema.dao;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.project314.screenSavvy.entity.UserAccount;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    
    //define field for entity manager 
    private EntityManager entityManager; 
    
    @Autowired
    //inject entity manager using constructor 
    public UserDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(UserAccount userAcc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        entityManager.persist(userAcc);
    }


}
```

ScreenSavvyApplication.java

```
package com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.project314.screenSavvy.dao.UserDAO;
import com.project314.screenSavvy.entity.UserAccount;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ScreenSavvyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SpringApplication.run(ScreenSavvyApplication.class, args);
    }
        
        @Bean 
        public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(UserDAO userDAO) {
            return runner -> {
                createUser(userDAO); 
            }; 
        }
        
        // ...
        private void createUser(UserDAO userDAO) {
            //create user object
            System.out.println("Creating user object");
            UserAccount userAcc = new UserAccount("John", "Smith","johnsmith@gmail.com","johnsmith123");
            
            //save user object
            System.out.println("Saving the user"); 
            userDAO.save(userAcc);
            
            System.out.println("Saved user. Generated id: " + userAcc.getId()); 
        }

    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.javaguides</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration-login-spring-boot-security-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>registration-login-spring-boot-security-thymeleaf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Thymeleaf and Hibernate </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File Working Tree
[image]

Comment: Please show your pom.xml (or gradle build).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've included it! thank you x

Comment: Your dao and entity are in wrong packages. They should be in the `.Cinema` subpackage. so `com.project314.screenSavvy.Cinema.dao` (and entity) instead f what you have now. Or remove the `cinema` part from the other packages. Either way they have to reside in the same package structure, currently they aren't.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah gosh i cant believe i left that out... thank you so much! xx